# Define maximum for NumerictUpDown in a dictionary

Tags: c#, winforms, dictionary, controls

So I have a dictionary with a few controls called `controlDict`. But if I want to set the maximum for a NumericUpDown control like this:

```
controlDict.Add("amountNum" + i.ToString(), new NumericUpDown());
            controlDict["amountNum" + i.ToString()].Location = new Point(60, 42);
controlDict["amountNum" + i.ToString()].Maximum = new decimal(new int[] {
            -1,
            -1,
            -1,
            0});
```

It gives me this error:

> 'Control' does not contain a definition for 'Maximum' and no extension method 'Maximum' accepting a first argument of type 'Control' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cast the control to `NumericUpDown` then assign values to its properties:

```
var numeric = (NumericUpDown)controlDict["amountNum" + i.ToString()];
numeric.Maximum = 100;
```

> Why `controlDict["amountNum" + i.ToString()].Location` works
>   without casting?

Because the result is `Control` and the control class has `Location` property. And all of your controls including `NumericUpDown` inherited from `Control`.

Items of your dictionary are of type `Control`. When you get an item from your dictionary using `controlDict["key"]` the result is of type `Control`. So you can access all properties of `Control` class. 
When you know the result control is specific control type, to have access to the specific control properties you should cast it to specific control type.

Answer (score 1):

This is because controlDict["amountNum" + i.ToString()] is Control instance.
Try this:

```
(controlDict["amountNum" + i.ToString()] as NumericUpDown).Maximum = new decimal(new int[] {
        -1,
        -1,
        -1,
        0});
```